# Is it better to use kids or young in the sentence? you can provide your suggestion

Tags: word-choice

I am writing some sentences.

> I want to be a nurse, I want to be a doctor...", is there anyone in the world who has not said these words when they were [kids / young / your suggestion]?

Comment: "They" in your sentence is singular, so "a kid" not "kids" is suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible completions for your sentence are

> is there anyone in the world who has not said these words when they were **a kid**?
>    is there anyone in the world who has not said these words when they were **young**?
>    is there anyone in the world who has not said these words when they were **growing up**?

all three have the meaning

> at an early stage in life